# QML ItemSelectionModel does not select?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a `TreeView` of a `QFileSystemModel` and an `ItemSelectionModel`:

```
ItemSelectionModel {
  id: sel
  model: fileSystemModel
  onSelectedIndexesChanged: {
    model.setSelected(selectedIndexes)
  }
}

TreeView {
  id: view
  anchors.fill: parent
  sortIndicatorVisible: true
  model: fileSystemModel
  rootIndex: rootPathIndex
  selection: sel
  selectionMode: 2
  TableViewColumn {
    id: namecolumn
    title: "Name"
    role: "fileName"
    resizable: true
    width: parent.width-sizeWidth-dateWidth-scrollBarWidth
    delegate: mycomp
  }
  ... other columns
}
```

When I sort the `TreeView` for the name or size of a file, the selection does not get updated. Therefore, in my fileSystemModel (derived from QFileSystemModel) I created a `Q_INVOKABLE` function which should store the selected indices:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void setSelected(QModelIndexList list) {
    _selectedIndices.clear();
    for(int i=0;i<list.count();i++) {
        _selectedIndices.append(QPersistentModelIndex(list[i]));
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure if this would work, as I am not sure whether the `ItemSelectionModel` indices are the same as the model indices.

After sorting, I thought I try to set the selection via retrieving this list, on the c++ side:

```
Q_INVOKABLE QVariantList getSelected() {
    return static_cast<QVariantList>(_selectedIndices);
}
```

and  in QML

```
onSortIndicatorOrderChanged: {
  var list = model.getSelected())
  console.log('new selection:')
  for(var idx in list) {
    console.log(list[idx])
    selection.select(list[idx],ItemSelectionModel.Select)
    console.log('now selected')
    console.log(selection.selectedIndexes)
  }
}
```

The debug output in `onSortIndicatorChanged` shows

```
qml: new selection:
qml: QPersistentModelIndex(5,0,0x1e2ad30,DisplayFileSystemModel(0x1544890))
qml: now selected
qml: 
sort by column 0
qml: new selection:
qml: QPersistentModelIndex(1,0,0x1e2ad30,DisplayFileSystemModel(0x1544890))
qml: now selected
qml:
```

if I toggle the sortIndicator. So it seems that the row of the `QPersistentModelIndex` gets updated correctly. However, `selection.selectedIndexes` is empty and no selection is shown. What am I missing?

A different way (maybe better) would be to access the QItemSelectionModel directly in c++, but I don't know how I would access that (without searching for its object name, which hurts reusability).

Comment: Did you see the examples that use a proxy model to do sorting and filtering?  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-customsortfiltermodel-example.html